# Django - registration login.html as index

Tags: python, django

My app is hosted on [shezankazi.pythonanywhere.com](http://shezankazi.pythonanywhere.com)

When I open this link I get to index.html. However I would like to open login.html directly as occurs when I choose "Anmelden" at the index page. Herefore I require assistance

This is my views.py

```
def index(request):
return render(request, 'crm/index.html')

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return '/crm/'
```

This is my app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from crm import views as crm_views
from person import views as person_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', crm_views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^crm/', include('crm.urls')),
    ...

]
```

And this is my crm/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from crm import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

And this is the end of my settings.py:

```
# If True, users can register
REGISTRATION_OPEN = False
# One-week activation window; you may, of course, use a different value.
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
# If True, the user will be automatically logged in.
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = False
# The page you want users to arrive at after they successful log in
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/crm/dashboard/'
# The page users are directed to if they are not logged in,
# and are trying to access pages requiring authentication
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
# The page users are directed to upon logging out
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login'
```

At first I changed the index view to render registration/login.html but then whenever I enter my credentials, the login page loads again instead of redirecting me to the dashboard.

Comment: Can you post the view for your registration page?

Comment: please see above, i added it

Answer (score 1):

change the order of the following two lines:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),,
```

and change the following:

```
return '/crm/dashboard/'
```